# print prime numbers in java in a simple way

Tags: java

I want to make a code to print all prime numbers .. I did this code in java .. I have a problem in my if statement in the isPrime method , I do not know how to implement it .. here is the code

```
public class PrimeList {

    private boolean [] numbers;

    /** Creates a complete filled out, the prime list of the numbers from 1 to n */
    public PrimeList(int n) {

        numbers = new boolean [n];
    }
    /** Prints all primes found */
    public void printPrimeList() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)==true) {
            sb.append(i +",");
        }
        }
        System.out.print(sb.toString());
        }

    /** Returns true if the NBR is a prime number that is listed,
    false in all other cases */
    public boolean isPrime(int nbr) { 
        if(nbr == 2) {
            return true;
        } else if (nbr/2 gives an int number && nbr/3 gives an int number ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrimeList primes = new PrimeList(100);
        primes.printPrimeList();

    }
}
```

As you see this line `else if (nbr/2 gives an int number && nbr/3 gives an int number ) {` I do not know how to implement it ??

please help me to implement this if statement ..

thanks :)

Comment: 1. what you want is probably not `&&` but `||`. 2. you can use the modulo function for such checks, i.e. `if (nbr % 2 == 0 || nbr % 3 == 0)...` . And 3. this is not how to check if a number is prime (hint: 25 is cannot be divided by 2 or 3, yet - it is not a prime number!).

Comment: Try modulo operator `%`. Agree with @alfasin about his comments

Comment: I agree with @alfasin this will be very inefficient

Comment: 25 is not a prime. 5 * 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is iterate over all integers `x` up to the squareroot of `nbr` and check if the remainder of `nbr / x` is `0`.

To get the remainder of a division operation, you must use the modulus operator `%`.

Example:

```
for (int i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(nbr); i++) {
    if (nbr % i == 0) {
        // we found a number that divides evenly into nbr without 
        // any remainder, therefore this number is not a prime.
        return false;
    }
} 
return true;
```

Will leave it as an exercise to figure out why you only need to iterate up to the square root.

Comment: thank you ,, what does Math.sqrt(nbr) means here ? I do not understand it

Comment: It means the square-root of `nbr`. So the square root of `25` is `5`. However it is an optimization, and you can simply do `for (int i=2; i<nbr; i++)` instead, but this will take much longer for big values of `nbr`.

Comment: You can use `i<Math.sqrt(nbr);` because if `i` equals the square root of `nbr`, then `nbr` is not a prime.

Comment: FYI - he is trying to print prime numbers less than/equal to nbr, not justdetermine if nbr is prime. So we need a loop outside of this loop.

Comment: @MartinKonecny My bad. Sorry, didn't notice.

Comment: God bless you all brothers .. it was helpful ,,thanks alot :)

Comment: Ok, I see - you return false when you detect a non-prime. My mistake - you are right.